# Altering collection property causes update to otherwise untouched record

Tags: nhibernate

I have three tables: Person, Role and PersonRole. Records in the Role table are rarely changed, so I have decided to add the Role table to NHibernate's 2nd level cache. Now several tests are failing, saying:

```
 ReadOnlyCache: Can't write to a readonly object ShipRepDAL.ShipRepDTO.Role
```

**Problem:**
Role records should not be updated by the application. My code is only touching the PersonRole collection on the Role object, so I do not understand why Nhibernate is updating a Role record.

Below is a sample of the code mapping from a business object to a Person entity. The sample adds a new Role:

```
[...]
var pr = new PersonRole
{
    Person = person,
    Role = role
};
person.PersonRoles.Add(pr);
role.PersonRoles.Add(pr); //If I comment out this line, it works - but then the Session will be out of sync
[...]
new PersonService().SaveOrUpdate(person); //Flush
```

Below is a sample of each table's mapping:

*Person*

```
<class name="Person" select-before-update="true" optimistic-lock="version" batch-size="25">
    [...]
    <version name="ModifiedDate" type="Timestamp" generated="always" />
    [...]
    <bag name="PersonRoles" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="PersonID"/>
        <one-to-many class="PersonRole" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

*PersonRole*

```
<class name="PersonRole" select-before-update="true" optimistic-lock="version" batch-size="25">
    [...]
    <version name="ModifiedDate" type="Timestamp" generated="always" />
    [...]       
    <many-to-one name="Person" column="PersonID" />
    <many-to-one name="Role" column="RoleID" />

</class>
```

*Role*

```
<class name="Role" select-before-update="true" optimistic-lock="version" batch-size="25">
    [...]
    <version name="ModifiedDate" type="Timestamp" generated="always" />
    [...]
    <bag name="PersonRoles" inverse="true">
        <key column="RoleID"/>
        <one-to-many class="PersonRole" />
    </bag>
    [...]
</class>
```

Any pointers as to what is wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is now quite different. You would have way more chances to get answers by asking a new question rather than editing this one. So it would be better to revert this one to its original version, and ask another question. (You may consider adding the actual cause of the initial question (the interceptor) as an answer here too, or delete the whole thing if you feel it is a too narrow case.)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I reverted to the original version and added a link to the new question in my answer below. I'd still like to keep the question up as you're answer was interesting.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

I do not see explicit reason for your trouble, apart you should very probably replace `bag` by `set` in your mappings.

## Details

There is a strange usage of `bag`, it should be `set` normally in your case. Or am I missing something?

A bag has a very special semantic, I would not be surprised if using it as you do causes NHibernate to touch your roles at each `PersonRole` change.

See [NHibernate reference](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-mapping), near the end of §6.2:

> A bag is an unordered, unindexed collection which may contain the same element multiple times.

May really your `PersonRoles` collections on `Role` or `Person` contains duplicated `PersonRole`?

And moreover, some lines farer still about bags:

> NHibernate can't create, delete or update rows individually, because there is no key that may be used to identify an individual row.

As your bag collection is not really one, you have no intermediate table between `PersonRole` and `Role` for holding your bag (no `table` attribute on `bag` mapping), and in such a case I guess that is `Role` which ends up being used as the bag table, thus causing NHibernate to touch it when you change `PersonRoles` collection.

Some more details in [Improving performances](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-collections-taxonomy), near the end of §19.5.1:

> Bags are the worst case. Since a bag permits duplicate element values and has no index column, no primary key may be defined. NHibernate has no way of distinguishing between duplicate rows. NHibernate resolves this problem by completely removing (in a single DELETE) and recreating the collection whenever it changes. This might be very inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I doubt bag vs set is the issue, but I'll keep the performance implications of bag in mind. Check out my edit though - I believe an Interceptor is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

After some further investigation the root cause turned out to be an Interceptor. A new question has been posted here: [Mask properties from dirty check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433215/mask-properties-from-dirty-check)

I'd still like to keep this question up as Frédéric's answer was interesting.